# Query regarding encryption mechanism in solidity

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, ether, smart-contract-wallets

can someone guide me regrading solidiry smart contracts does remix Ide or solidity use some encryption mechamism for its contract data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encryption in solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/47553/encryption-in-solidity)

Comment: my question is that is there any encryption mechanism which is using by solidity?  When i do coding on remix then the input value which we deploy is encrypted or not?

Comment: The only encryption I'm aware is at the p2p protocol between nodes to exchange blocks and transactions, a sort of ssl to authenticate each other.